# ASP.NET MVC: is calling an action Post or Get?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

When you simply type a web address such as:

```
http://localhost/MyController/MyAction
```

this calls the `MyAction` function inside the `MyController` class.

My question: is this request an HttpPost, an HttpGet, or neither?

Answer (score 1):

Its a GET request when the browser calls a url.

Answer (score 1):

It is a HTTP GET by default.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Foo(){

}
```

This would be HTTPPOST.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you simple type in a url in the browser results in a `GET` request.

You can specifiy the accepted http method (verb) by using the several attributes.

- [HttpPost]
- [HttpPut]
- [HttpGet]
- [HttpDelete]

Answer (score 0):

It is a `GET` request.

`POST` requires are usually when a form is submitted